# Running a .php file from the command line?

Tags: php, command-line, cmd

I want run a `.php` file in the command line, but I can’t.

When I get to the file and want to run was opened with IDE:

```
>cd c:\wamp\www\GXC-CMS-2-master\GXC-CMS-2-master

core\cms\cms.php
```

Should certain system settings to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
C:\path\to\php.exe file.php
```